# SwiftyJson and firestore timestamp swift

Tags: json, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have my dictionary [String:Any] without timestamp object which I am sending it to firestore.
Everything works good sending and retrieving the object.

When I add a timestamp element on the dictionary with the following way

```
data["timestamp"] = FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

it commits successfully.But when I retrieve it. if I do

```
 let data = document.data()
 print(data)
```

I can see the debug message then I parse it to SwiftyJson (https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

```
let json = JSON(data)
print(json)
```

the message that I receive from this debug is "unknown" and fails on

```
let createdAtTimestamp: Timestamp = data["timestamp"] as! Timestamp
```

any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you modifying the initial configuration for `areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled` when you retrieve it the data?

[Firestore returns timestamps fields as NSDate as default](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/FirestoreSettings#/c:objc(cs)FIRFirestoreSettings(py)timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled), so maybe this is the issue.

If you set this property to `true`, you can now handle it as `FIRTimestamp`:

```
let createdAtTimestamp: FIRTimestamp = data["timestamp"] as! FIRTimestamp
```

Comment: yes, I do 


 `let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let settings = db.settings
        settings.areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled = true
        db.settings = settings`


It seems to be on the library not be able to handle FIRTimestamp(when I use FIRTimestamp warns me that has renamed on Timestamp)

I am testing now another library(Object Mapper) to see how it handles it. else I will mention it on the GitHub of SwiftyJSON

Comment: You are right about the renaming of the property.

Also, maybe you are in the correct path, because I tried the assignation without using a third party library for JSON process and works correctly. Please let me know if you found that the other library is working with the same code.

Comment: The timestamps of firestorm works fine with the ObjectMapper (https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) library. Had to replace all the references but anyway. I don't know if in the future swiftjson will support it but in the future if someone plans to use firestore and swiftyjson should try to set and get a timestamp before continues to intergration

Comment: @Haris I am using ObjectMapper but I am not able to access FIRTimestamp.
Here is my question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59390181/ios-error-invalid-type-in-json-write-firtimestamp