# iOS error 'Invalid type in JSON write (FIRTimestamp)'

Tags: ios, firebase, swift4, codable

I am trying to map my data to Model.
Where I am using Firestore snapshot listener, to get data.
here, I am **getting data and mapping to "User" model** that;

```
            do{
                let user = try User(dictionary: tempUserDic)
                print("\(user.firstName)")
            }
            catch{
                print("error occurred")
            }
```

Here is my **Model:**

```
struct User {
    let firstName: String
//    var lon: Double = 0.0
//    var refresh:Int = 0
//    var createdOn: Timestamp = Timestamp()
}

//Testing Codable
extension User: Codable {
    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) throws {
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary))
    }
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case firstName = "firstName"
    }
}
```

Correct me if I am wrong.

**Crashing because I am getting "Timestamp" in data.**

**Data getting from listener :**

**User Dictionary**:

```
[\"firstName\": Ruchira,
 \"lastInteraction\": FIRTimestamp: seconds=1576566738 nanoseconds=846000000>]"
```

**How to map "Timestamp" to Model?**

Tried "CodableFirstore" https://github.com/alickbass/CodableFirebase

Comment: The code doesn't ***write*** anything. To map the data to a model you have to make `Timestamp` conform to `Codable`. `ObjectMapper` is not necessary.

Comment: @vadian I am not using "ObjectMapper". 
when I am trying to use "Timestamp" in Codable, it is not allowing me.

Comment: Use a representation of `FIRTimestamp` which is `Codable` compatible like `Date`.

Comment: I think this error is from JSONSerializaton not from Codable

Answer (score 2):

An approach is to create an extension to type `Dictionary` that coverts a dictionary to any other type, but automatically modifies `Date` and `Timestamp` types to writeable JSON strings.

This is the code:

```
extension Dictionary {

    func decodeTo<T>(_ type: T.Type) -> T? where T: Decodable {
        
        var dict = self

        // This block will change any Date and Timestamp type to Strings
        dict.filter {
            $0.value is Date || $0.value is Timestamp
        }.forEach {
            if $0.value is Date {
                let date = $0.value as? Date ?? Date()
                dict[$0.key] = date.timestampString as? Value
            } else if $0.value is Timestamp {
                let date = $0.value as? Timestamp ?? Timestamp()
                dict[$0.key] = date.dateValue().timestampString as? Value
            }
        }

        let jsonData = (try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: [])) ?? nil
        if let jsonData {
            return (try? JSONDecoder().decode(type, from: jsonData)) ?? nil
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

The `.timestampString` method is also declared in an extension for type `Date`:

```
extension Date {
    
    var timestampString: String {
        Date.timestampFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
    
    static private var timestampFormatter: DateFormatter {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
        return dateFormatter
    }
}
```

Usage, like in the case of the question:

```
let user = tempUserDict.decodeTo(User.self)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by converting the `FIRTimestamp` fields to `Double` (seconds) so the `JSONSerialization` could parse it accordingly.

```swift
 let items: [T] = documents.compactMap { query in
   var data = query.data() // get a copy of the data to be modified.

   // If any of the fields value is a `FIRTimestamp` we replace it for a `Double`.
   if let index = (data.keys.firstIndex{ data[$0] is FIRTimestamp }) {

     // Convert the field to `Timestamp`
     let timestamp: Timestamp = data[data.keys[index]] as! Timestamp

     // Get the seconds of it and replace it on the `copy` of `data`.
     data[data.keys[index]] = timestamp.seconds

    }

    // This should not complain anymore.
    guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(
       withJSONObject: data, 
       options: .prettyPrinted
    ) else { return nil }

    // Make sure your decoder setups the decoding strategy to `. secondsSince1970` (see timestamp.seconds documentation).
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
    return try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
 }

// Use now your beautiful `items`
return .success(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that Firestore natively handles timestamp conversion via `documentReference.data(as: )`; so instead of accessing the data dictionary yourself, you can pass it in such as: `documentReference.data(as: User.self)`.

The existing solutions implement additional decoding logic which I believe should already be handled by `Timestamp`'s conformance to Codable. And they'll run into issues with nested timestamps.

- Via [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/swift-codable-data-mapping#mapping_to_and_from_simple_types_in_documents_using_codable): `Use documentReference.data(as: ) to map a document reference to a Swift type.`